# How do I convert a String object into a Hash object?

Tags: ruby

I have a string which looks like a hash:

```
"{ :key_a => { :key_1a => 'value_1a', :key_2a => 'value_2a' }, :key_b => { :key_1b => 'value_1b' } }"
```

How do I get a Hash out of it? like:

```
{ :key_a => { :key_1a => 'value_1a', :key_2a => 'value_2a' }, :key_b => { :key_1b => 'value_1b' } }
```

The string can have any depth of nesting. It has all the properties how a valid Hash is typed in Ruby.

Comment: I think eval will do something here. Let me test first. I posted the question too early I think. :)

Comment: Ohh yeah just pass it to the eval. :)

Answer (score 86, accepted):

The string created by calling `Hash#inspect` can be turned back into a hash by calling `eval` on it. However, this requires the same to be true of all of the objects in the hash.

If I start with the hash `{:a => Object.new}`, then its string representation is `"{:a=>#<Object:0x7f66b65cf4d0>}"`, and I can't use `eval` to turn it back into a hash because `#<Object:0x7f66b65cf4d0>` isn't valid Ruby syntax.

However, if all that's in the hash is strings, symbols, numbers, and arrays, it should work, because those have string representations that are  valid Ruby syntax.

Comment: "if all that's in the hash is strings, symbols, and numbers,". This says a lot. So I can check the validity of a string to be `eval`uated as a hash by making sure that the above statement is valid for that string.

Comment: Yes, but in order to do that you either need a full Ruby parser, or you need to know where the string came from in the first place and know that it can only generate strings, symbols, and numbers. (See also Toms Mikoss's answer about trusting the contents of the string.)

Comment: Be carefule where you use this. Using `eval` at the wrong place is a huge security hole. Anything inside the string, will be evaluated. So imagine if in an API someone injected `rm -fr`

Answer (score 215):

For different string, you can do it without using dangerous `eval` method:

```
hash_as_string = "{\"0\"=>{\"answer\"=>\"1\", \"value\"=>\"No\"}, \"1\"=>{\"answer\"=>\"2\", \"value\"=>\"Yes\"}, \"2\"=>{\"answer\"=>\"3\", \"value\"=>\"No\"}, \"3\"=>{\"answer\"=>\"4\", \"value\"=>\"1\"}, \"4\"=>{\"value\"=>\"2\"}, \"5\"=>{\"value\"=>\"3\"}, \"6\"=>{\"value\"=>\"4\"}}"
JSON.parse hash_as_string.gsub('=>', ':')
```

Comment: This answer should be selected for avoiding using eval.

Comment: you should also replace nils, f.e. `JSON.parse(hash_as_string.gsub("=>", ":").gsub(":nil,", ":null,"))`

Comment: @YoLudke's reply is a good idea, but it only substitutes nils that are followed by a comma, so it will break if your hash ends with a nil value. Using word boundaries is more flexible: `JSON.parse(hash_as_string.gsub("=>", ":").gsub(/\bnil\b/, "null"))`.

Answer (score 156):

Quick and dirty method would be

```
eval("{ :key_a => { :key_1a => 'value_1a', :key_2a => 'value_2a' }, :key_b => { :key_1b => 'value_1b' } }")
```

But it has severe security implications.
It executes whatever it is passed, you must be 110% sure (as in, at least no user input anywhere along the way) it would contain only properly formed hashes or unexpected bugs/horrible creatures from outer space might start popping up.

Comment: I have a light saber with me. I can take care of those creatures and bugs. :)

Comment: USING EVAL can be dangerous here, according to my teacher. Eval takes any ruby code and runs it. The danger here is analogous to SQL injection danger. Gsub is preferable.

Comment: Example string showing why David's teacher is correct: '{:surprise => "#{system \"rm -rf * \"}"}'

Comment: I cannot emphasize the DANGER of using EVAL here enough!  This is absolutely forbidden if user input can ever wind its way into your string.

Comment: Even if you think you'll never open this up more publicly, someone else might.  We all (should) know how code gets used in ways you wouldn't have expected.  It's like putting extremely heavy things on a high shelf, making it top heavy.  You should just never create this form of danger.

Comment: @Waseem A lightsaber won't protect you from viruses, malware, hackers, etc.

Answer (score 35):

I had the same problem. I was storing a hash in Redis. When retrieving that hash, it was a string. I didn't want to call `eval(str)` because of security concerns. My solution was to save the hash as a json string instead of a ruby hash string. If you have the option, using json is easier.

```
  redis.set(key, ruby_hash.to_json)
  JSON.parse(redis.get(key))
```

TL;DR: use `to_json` and `JSON.parse`

Comment: This is the best answer by far. ```to_json``` and ```JSON.parse```

Comment: To whoever downvoted me. Why? I had the same issue, trying to convert a string representation of a ruby hash into an actual hash object. I realized that I was trying to solve the wrong problem. I realized that solving the question asked here was error prone and insecure. I realized that I needed to store my data differently and use a format that is designed to safely serialize and deserialize objects. 

TL;DR: I had the same question as OP, and realized that the answer was to ask a different question.

Also, if you down-vote me, please provide feedback so we can all learn together.

Comment: Downvoting without an explanatory comment is the cancer of Stack Overflow.

Comment: yes downvoting should require an explanation and show who downvotes.

Comment: To make this answer even more applicable to the OP's question, if your string representation of a hash is called 'strungout' you should be able to do  hashit = JSON.parse(strungout.to_json) and then select your items inside hashit via hashit['keyname'] as normal.

Comment: I also use this way

Comment: this works just perfect, thanks

Comment: I agree that this is a much better option than eval. Thanks!

Answer (score 27):

Maybe YAML.load ?

Comment: (load method supports strings)

Comment: That requires a totally different string representation, but it much, much safer. (And the string representation is just as easy to generate -- just call #to_yaml, rather than #inspect)

Comment: Wow. I had no idea it was so easy to parse strings w/ yaml. It takes my chain of linux bash commands that generate data and intelligently turns it into a ruby Hash w/o any string format massaging.

Comment: This and to_yaml solves my problem since I have some control of the way the string is generated. Thanks!

Answer (score 26):

The solutions so far cover some cases but miss some (see below). Here's my attempt at a more thorough (safe) conversion. I know of one corner case which this solution doesn't handle which is single character symbols made up of odd, but allowed characters. For example `{:> => :<}` is a valid ruby hash.

I put this [code up on github as well](https://gist.github.com/gene1wood/bd8159ad90b0799d9436). This code starts with a test string to exercise all the conversions

```rb
require 'json'

# Example ruby hash string which exercises all of the permutations of position and type
# See http://json.org/
ruby_hash_text='{"alpha"=>{"first second > third"=>"first second > third", "after comma > foo"=>:symbolvalue, "another after comma > foo"=>10}, "bravo"=>{:symbol=>:symbolvalue, :aftercomma=>10, :anotheraftercomma=>"first second > third"}, "charlie"=>{1=>10, 2=>"first second > third", 3=>:symbolvalue}, "delta"=>["first second > third", "after comma > foo"], "echo"=>[:symbol, :aftercomma], "foxtrot"=>[1, 2]}'

puts ruby_hash_text

# Transform object string symbols to quoted strings
ruby_hash_text.gsub!(/([{,]\s*):([^>\s]+)\s*=>/, '\1"\2"=>')

# Transform object string numbers to quoted strings
ruby_hash_text.gsub!(/([{,]\s*)([0-9]+\.?[0-9]*)\s*=>/, '\1"\2"=>')

# Transform object value symbols to quotes strings
ruby_hash_text.gsub!(/([{,]\s*)(".+?"|[0-9]+\.?[0-9]*)\s*=>\s*:([^,}\s]+\s*)/, '\1\2=>"\3"')

# Transform array value symbols to quotes strings
ruby_hash_text.gsub!(/([\[,]\s*):([^,\]\s]+)/, '\1"\2"')

# Transform object string object value delimiter to colon delimiter
ruby_hash_text.gsub!(/([{,]\s*)(".+?"|[0-9]+\.?[0-9]*)\s*=>/, '\1\2:')

puts ruby_hash_text

puts JSON.parse(ruby_hash_text)
```

Here are some notes on the other solutions here

- [@Ken Bloom](https://stackoverflow.com/users/197788/ken-bloom) and [@Toms Mikoss](https://stackoverflow.com/users/123144/toms-mikoss)'s solutions use `eval` which is too scary for me (as Toms rightly points out).
- [@zolter](https://stackoverflow.com/users/753891/zolter)'s [solution](https://stackoverflow.com/a/22820407/168874) works if your hash has no symbols or numeric keys.
- [@jackquack](https://stackoverflow.com/users/700391/jackquack)'s [solution](https://stackoverflow.com/a/9910355/168874) works if there are no quoted strings mixed in with the symbols.
- [@Eugene](https://stackoverflow.com/users/1099933/eugene)'s [solution](https://stackoverflow.com/a/25205872/168874) works if your symbols don't use all the allowed characters ([symbol literals have a broader set of allowed characters](https://gist.github.com/gene1wood/a70fa860cfa2a527879b)).
- [@Pablo](https://stackoverflow.com/users/1047055/pablo)'s [solution](https://stackoverflow.com/a/8338538/168874) works as long as you don't have a mix of symbols and quoted strings.

Comment: Very cool solution.  You could add a gsub of all `:nil` to `:null` to handle that particular weirdness.

Comment: This solution also has the bonus of working on multi-level hashes recursively, since it leverages JSON#parse. I had some trouble with nesting on other solutions.

Comment: Found the regexes a little hard to follow, so created a gist for this with some test cases. https://gist.github.com/akagr/0339fb80f1b268a48a43ffbd1606cb3b

Thanks for answer!

Answer (score 25):

This short little snippet will do it, but I can't see it working with a nested hash. I think it's pretty cute though

```
STRING.gsub(/[{}:]/,'').split(', ').map{|h| h1,h2 = h.split('=>'); {h1 => h2}}.reduce(:merge)
```

Steps
1. I eliminate the '{','}' and the ':'
2. I split upon the string wherever it finds a ','
3. I split each of the substrings that were created with the split, whenever it finds a '=>'. Then, I create a hash with the two sides of the hash I just split apart.
4. I am left with an array of hashes which I then merge together.

EXAMPLE INPUT: "{:user_id=>11, :blog_id=>2, :comment_id=>1}"
RESULT OUTPUT: {"user_id"=>"11", "blog_id"=>"2", "comment_id"=>"1"}

Comment: That is one sick oneliner ! :) +1

Comment: Won't this also strip away `{}:` characters from *values* inside the stringified hash?

Comment: @VladimirPanteleev You're right, it would. Nice catch! You can do my code reviews any day :)

Answer (score 12):

I prefer to abuse ActiveSupport::JSON.  Their approach is to convert the hash to yaml and then load it.  Unfortunately the conversion to yaml isn't simple and you'd probably want to borrow it from AS if you don't have AS in your project already.

We also have to convert any symbols into regular string-keys as symbols aren't appropriate in JSON.

However, its unable to handle hashes that have a date string in them (our date strings end up not being surrounded by strings, which is where the big issue comes in):

string = '{'last_request_at' : 2011-12-28 23:00:00 UTC }'
`ActiveSupport::JSON.decode(string.gsub(/:([a-zA-z])/,'\\1').gsub('=>', ' : '))`

Would result in an invalid JSON string error when it tries to parse the date value.

Would love any suggestions on how to handle this case

Comment: Thanks for the pointer to .decode, it worked great for me. I needed to convert a JSON response to test it. Here's the code I used: `ActiveSupport::JSON.decode(response.body, symbolize_keys: true)`

Answer (score 12):

works in rails 4.1 and support symbols without quotes {:a => 'b'}

just add this to initializers folder:

```
class String
  def to_hash_object
    JSON.parse(self.gsub(/:([a-zA-z]+)/,'"\\1"').gsub('=>', ': ')).symbolize_keys
  end
end
```

Comment: Works on the command line, but I get "stack level to deep" when I put this in an intializer...

Answer (score 4):

Please consider this solution. Library+spec:

File: `lib/ext/hash/from_string.rb`:

```
require "json"

module Ext
  module Hash
    module ClassMethods
      # Build a new object from string representation.
      #
      #   from_string('{"name"=>"Joe"}')
      #
      # @param s [String]
      # @return [Hash]
      def from_string(s)
        s.gsub!(/(?<!\\)"=>nil/, '":null')
        s.gsub!(/(?<!\\)"=>/, '":')
        JSON.parse(s)
      end
    end
  end
end

class Hash    #:nodoc:
  extend Ext::Hash::ClassMethods
end
```

File: `spec/lib/ext/hash/from_string_spec.rb`:

```
require "ext/hash/from_string"

describe "Hash.from_string" do
  it "generally works" do
    [
      # Basic cases.
      ['{"x"=>"y"}', {"x" => "y"}],
      ['{"is"=>true}', {"is" => true}],
      ['{"is"=>false}', {"is" => false}],
      ['{"is"=>nil}', {"is" => nil}],
      ['{"a"=>{"b"=>"c","ar":[1,2]}}', {"a" => {"b" => "c", "ar" => [1, 2]}}],
      ['{"id"=>34030, "users"=>[14105]}', {"id" => 34030, "users" => [14105]}],

      # Tricky cases.
      ['{"data"=>"{\"x\"=>\"y\"}"}', {"data" => "{\"x\"=>\"y\"}"}],   # Value is a `Hash#inspect` string which must be preserved.
    ].each do |input, expected|
      output = Hash.from_string(input)
      expect([input, output]).to eq [input, expected]
    end
  end # it
end
```

Comment: `it "generally works"`  but not necessarily? I would be more verbose in those tests.

`it "converts strings to object" { expect('...').to eql ... }`

`it "supports nested objects" { expect('...').to eql ... }`

Comment: Hey @Lex, what method does is described in its RubyDoc comment. The test better not re-state it, it'll create unnecessary details as passive text. Thus, "generally works" is a nice formula to state that stuff, well, generally works. Cheers!

Comment: Yeah, at the end of the day whatever works. Any tests are better than no tests. Personally I'm a fan of explicit descriptions, but thats just a preference.

Answer (score 3):

Here is a method using [whitequark/parser](https://github.com/whitequark/parser) which is safer than both `gsub` and `eval` methods.

It makes the following assumptions about the data:

1. Hash keys are assumed to be a string, symbol, or integer.
2. Hash values are assumed to be a string, symbol, integer, boolean, nil, array, or a hash.

```rb
# frozen_string_literal: true

require 'parser/current'

class HashParser
  # Type error is used to handle unexpected types when parsing stringified hashes.
  class TypeError < ::StandardError
    attr_reader :message, :type

    def initialize(message, type)
      @message = message
      @type = type
    end
  end

  def hash_from_s(str_hash)
    ast = Parser::CurrentRuby.parse(str_hash)

    unless ast.type == :hash
      puts "expected data to be a hash but got #{ast.type}"
      return
    end

    parse_hash(ast)
  rescue Parser::SyntaxError => e
    puts "error parsing hash: #{e.message}"
  rescue TypeError => e
    puts "unexpected type (#{e.type}) encountered while parsing: #{e.message}"
  end

  private

  def parse_hash(hash)
    out = {}
    hash.children.each do |node|
      unless node.type == :pair
        raise TypeError.new("expected child of hash to be a `pair`", node.type)
      end

      key, value = node.children

      key = parse_key(key)
      value = parse_value(value)

      out[key] = value
    end

    out
  end

  def parse_key(key)
    case key.type
    when :sym, :str, :int
      key.children.first
    else
      raise TypeError.new("expected key to be either symbol, string, or integer", key.type)
    end
  end

  def parse_value(value)
    case value.type
    when :sym, :str, :int
      value.children.first
    when :true
      true
    when :false
      false
    when :nil
      nil
    when :array
      value.children.map { |c| parse_value(c) }
    when :hash
      parse_hash(value)
    else
      raise TypeError.new("value of a pair was an unexpected type", value.type)
    end
  end
end
```

and here are some rspec tests verifying that it works as expected:

```rb
# frozen_string_literal: true

require 'spec_helper'

RSpec.describe HashParser do
  describe '#hash_from_s' do
    subject { described_class.new.hash_from_s(input) }

    context 'when input contains forbidden types' do
      where(:input) do
        [
          'def foo; "bar"; end',
          '`cat somefile`',
          'exec("cat /etc/passwd")',
          '{:key=>Env.fetch("SOME_VAR")}',
          '{:key=>{:another_key=>Env.fetch("SOME_VAR")}}',
          '{"key"=>"value: #{send}"}'
        ]
      end

      with_them do
        it 'returns nil' do
          expect(subject).to be_nil
        end
      end
    end

    context 'when input cannot be parsed' do
      let(:input) { "{" }

      it 'returns nil' do
        expect(subject).to be_nil
      end
    end

    context 'with valid input' do
      using RSpec::Parameterized::TableSyntax

      where(:input, :expected) do
        '{}'                          | {}
        '{"bool"=>true}'              | { 'bool' => true }
        '{"bool"=>false}'             | { 'bool' => false }
        '{"nil"=>nil}'                | { 'nil' => nil }
        '{"array"=>[1, "foo", nil]}'  | { 'array' => [1, "foo", nil] }
        '{foo: :bar}'                 | { foo: :bar }
        '{foo: {bar: "bin"}}'         | { foo: { bar: "bin" } }
      end

      with_them do
        specify { expect(subject).to eq(expected) }
      end
    end
  end
end
```

Answer (score 2):

I built a gem [hash_parser](https://github.com/bibstha/ruby_hash_parser) that first checks if a hash is safe or not using `ruby_parser` gem. Only then, it applies the `eval`.

You can use it as

```
require 'hash_parser'

# this executes successfully
a = "{ :key_a => { :key_1a => 'value_1a', :key_2a => 'value_2a' }, 
       :key_b => { :key_1b => 'value_1b' } }"
p HashParser.new.safe_load(a)

# this throws a HashParser::BadHash exception
a = "{ :key_a => system('ls') }"
p HashParser.new.safe_load(a)
```

The tests in https://github.com/bibstha/ruby_hash_parser/blob/master/test/test_hash_parser.rb give you more examples of the things I've tested to make sure eval is safe.

Answer (score 2):

This method works for one level deep hash

```
  def convert_to_hash(str)
    return unless str.is_a?(String)

    hash_arg = str.gsub(/[^'"\w\d]/, ' ').squish.split.map { |x| x.gsub(/['"]/, '') }
    Hash[*hash_arg]
  end
```

example

```
> convert_to_hash("{ :key_a => 'value_a', :key_b => 'value_b', :key_c => '' }")
=> {"key_a"=>"value_a", "key_b"=>"value_b", "key_c"=>""}
```

Answer (score 1):

I came to this question after writing a one-liner for this purpose, so I share my code in case it helps somebody. Works for a string with only one level depth and possible empty values (but not nil), like:

```
"{ :key_a => 'value_a', :key_b => 'value_b', :key_c => '' }"
```

The code is:

```
the_string = '...'
the_hash = Hash.new
the_string[1..-2].split(/, /).each {|entry| entryMap=entry.split(/=>/); value_str = entryMap[1]; the_hash[entryMap[0].strip[1..-1].to_sym] = value_str.nil? ? "" : value_str.strip[1..-2]}
```

Answer (score 1):

Ran across a similar issue that needed to use the eval().

My situation, I was pulling some data from an API and writing it to a file locally. Then being able to pull the data from the file and use the Hash.

I used IO.read() to read the contents of the file into a variable. In this case IO.read() creates it as a String.

Then used eval() to convert the string into a Hash.

```
read_handler = IO.read("Path/To/File.json")

puts read_handler.kind_of?(String) # Returns TRUE

a = eval(read_handler)

puts a.kind_of?(Hash) # Returns TRUE

puts a["Enter Hash Here"] # Returns Key => Values

puts a["Enter Hash Here"].length # Returns number of key value pairs

puts a["Enter Hash Here"]["Enter Key Here"] # Returns associated value
```

Also just to mention that IO is an ancestor of File. So you can also use File.read instead if you wanted.

Answer (score 1):

I had a similar issue when trying to convert a string to a hash in Ruby.

The result from my computations was this:

```
{
 "coord":{"lon":24.7535,"lat":59.437},
 "weather":[{"id":803,"main":"Clouds","description":"broken clouds","icon":"04d"}],
 "base":"stations",
 "main":{"temp":283.34,"feels_like":281.8,"temp_min":282.33,"temp_max":283.34,"pressure":1021,"humidity":53},
 "visibility":10000,
 "wind":{"speed":3.09,"deg":310},
 "clouds":{"all":75},
 "dt":1652808506,
 "sys":{"type":1,"id":1330,"country":"EE","sunrise":1652751796,"sunset":1652813502},
 "timezone":10800,"id":588409,"name":"Tallinn","cod":200
 }
```

I checked the type value and confirmed that it was of the **String** type using the command below:

```
result = 
{
 "coord":{"lon":24.7535,"lat":59.437},
 "weather":[{"id":803,"main":"Clouds","description":"broken clouds","icon":"04d"}],
 "base":"stations",
 "main":{"temp":283.34,"feels_like":281.8,"temp_min":282.33,"temp_max":283.34,"pressure":1021,"humidity":53},
 "visibility":10000,
 "wind":{"speed":3.09,"deg":310},
 "clouds":{"all":75},
 "dt":1652808506,
 "sys":{"type":1,"id":1330,"country":"EE","sunrise":1652751796,"sunset":1652813502},
 "timezone":10800,"id":588409,"name":"Tallinn","cod":200
 }

puts result.instance_of? String
puts result.instance_of? Hash
```

**Here's how I solved it**:

All I had to do was run the command below to convert it from a **String** to a **Hash**:

```
result_new = JSON.parse(result, symbolize_names: true)
```

And then checked the type value again using the commands below:

```
puts result_new.instance_of? String
puts result_new.instance_of? Hash
```

This time it returned `true` for the **Hash**