# How to parse a string representation of a hash

Tags: ruby, hash

I have this string and I'm wondering how to convert it to a Hash.

```
"{:account_id=>4444, :deposit_id=>3333}"
```

Comment: try this:

http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1667630/how-do-i-convert-a-string-object-into-a-hash-object

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Guess I never posted my workaround for this... Here it goes,

```
# strip the hash down
stringy_hash = "account_id=>4444, deposit_id=>3333"

# turn string into hash
Hash[stringy_hash.split(",").collect{|x| x.strip.split("=>")}]
```

Comment: This will fail to split fields correctly if you have any data that contains a `,` or `=>`. `{ :text => "Welcome, friends.", delim => "=>" }`

Answer (score 17):

The way suggested in miku's answer is indeed easiest and **unsafest**.

```
# DO NOT RUN IT
eval '{:surprise => "#{system \"rm -rf / \"}"}'
# SERIOUSLY, DON'T
```

Consider using a different string representation of your hashes, e.g. [JSON](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5410682/parsing-a-json-string-in-ruby) or YAML. It's way more secure and at least equally robust.

Comment: nop these are rails post params so i guess i can't use json or yaml

Comment: Interesting. Controllers in Rails usually receive `POST` params as Ruby objects. How come you get them as a string?

Comment: lets hope no one runs that to "see what it will do" :-/

Comment: @Pavling, good point. I've added an appropriate piece of advice.

Comment: Actually, I'm sending these as [custom options for paypal](https://cms.paypal.com/us/cgi-bin/?cmd=_render-content&content_ID=developer/e_howto_html_Appx_websitestandard_htmlvariables) like this `:custom => {:account_id => @account.id, :deposit_id => @deposit.id}`. So, when paypal posts back the IPN the hash is quoted as string in the controller.

Is there any other way to send multiple variables with paypal custom options altogether?

Comment: @zoras, I guess it's a candidate for a new question with a [tag:paypal] tag.

Comment: this takes really long when I run it

Comment: yeah maybe at least explain what the code you wrote does. i feel like it's v possible someone new to ruby/coding might run it anyway just to see. so for that person: it would delete all of your files.

Comment: You should add `--no-preserve-root` to your example to really kick balls! :-P

Comment: don't forget to add `sudo` before `system`

Answer (score 16):

With a little replacement, you may use YAML:

```
require 'yaml'

p YAML.load(
  "{:account_id=>4444, :deposit_id=>3333}".gsub(/=>/, ': ')
  )
```

But this works only for this specific, simple string. Depending on your real data you may get problems.

Comment: Worked like a charm!  I passed mine into `HashWithIndifferentAccess.new` to get a hash like the param hash.

Comment: This would only work with data types that are native to YAML. A regular expression, for example, wouldn't be parseable in this way.

Answer (score 12):

if your string hash is some sort of like this (it can be nested or plain hash)

```
stringify_hash = "{'account_id'=>4444, 'deposit_id'=>3333, 'nested_key'=>{'key1' => val1, 'key2' => val2, 'key3' => nil}}"
```

you can convert it into hash like this without using eval which is dangerous

```
desired_hash = JSON.parse(stringify_hash.gsub("'",'"').gsub('=>',':').gsub('nil','null'))
```

and for the one you posted where the key is a symbol you can use like this

```
JSON.parse(string_hash.gsub(':','"').gsub('=>','":'))
```

Comment: Hashes contain 'null' for null objects, where as this contains 'nil', so that would need to be replaced too.

Answer (score 11):

The easiest and **unsafest** would be to just evaluate the string:

```
>> s = "{:account_id=>4444, :deposit_id=>3333}"
>> h = eval(s)
=> {:account_id=>4444, :deposit_id=>3333}
>> h.class
=> Hash
```

Comment: I'm getting these in rails post params. Isn't there a safe way to convert string into hash other than eval.

Comment: I don't know your setup, but maybe it would be easier to get back a hash in the first place. Otherwise, ruby supports some TAINT levels, see: http://www.ruby-doc.org/docs/ProgrammingRuby/html/taint.html