# String to Hash conversion

Tags: ruby, string, hash

How i can convert string into hash?

now i use:

```
eval "{'1627207:28320'=>'text'}"
=> {'1627207:28320'=>'text'}
```

but "eval" is not good for my case - string passed from params, and such case it is not secure

**Edited:**

passed string can also be:

`"{'1627207'=>'text', '11:167:28320'=>'text 1 / text 2 / unicode=>привет!'}"`

Then need result hash:

```
{'1627207:28320'=>'text',
'11:167:28320'=>'text 1 / text 2 / unicode=>привет!'}
```

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/a/9910355/1275603 maybe something like that

Comment: I guess the real question is, why are you letting your users pass Ruby code to your application? Why not a format that you can parse safely, like JSON?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

```
str = "{'1627207:28320'=>'text'}"
p Hash[*str.delete("{}'").split('=>')] #{"1627207:28320"=>"text"}
```

edit for different input:

```
str = "{'1627207:28320'=>'text', 'key2'=>'text2'}" 
p Hash[*str.delete("{}'").split(/=>|, /)] #{"1627207:28320"=>"text", "key2"=>"text2"}
```

Comment: it is fine, but user can pass "{'1627207:28320'=>'text', 'key2'=>'text2'}" string.  Then error: `ArgumentError: odd number of arguments for Hash
 from (irb):in `[]'

Answer (score 2):

```
class String
  def to_h
    h={}
    self.scan(/'(\w+.\w+)'=>'(\w+)'/).each { |k,v| h[k]=v }
    h
  end
end

p "{'1627207:28320'=>'text','test'=>'text2'}".to_h
=>{"1627207:28320"=>"text", "test"=>"text2"}
```

EDIT: shorter version

```
class String
  def to_h
    Hash[self.scan(/'([^']+)'=>'([^']+)'/)]
  end
end
```

Comment: worked for: `"{'key'=>'texttext' }"` but not worked for `"{'key'=>'text text' }"`

Comment: well, the regex needs to be oriented towards the kind of inpout that needs to be processed, adapted the shorter version to look for the char ' as delimiter

Answer (score 0):

Quite straight forward:

```
$ irb
irb(main):001:0> k='1627207:28320'
=> "1627207:28320"
irb(main):002:0> v='text'
=> "text"
irb(main):003:0> h={k => v}
=> {"1627207:28320"=>"text"}
irb(main):004:0> h
=> {"1627207:28320"=>"text"}
irb(main):005:0>
```

Comment: But you don't parse string, just creating a hash from variables

Comment: What kind of parsing he does? In his example he gets from text to hash. If he gets an string looking like a hash then parsing is necessary as Grzegorz pointed out

Comment: He gets `"{'some_key' => 'value'}"` string, but also could get `"{'first' => 1, 'second' => 2}"`, becouse both strings contains hash. So he need a code that could convert all string to hash

Comment: In that case parsing is needed, maybe he could use JSON.decode()

Comment: Parsing is necessary to interpolate the string content. Even you use eval, JSON or other libraries, they do the same thing.

Answer (score 0):

You could simply try this:

```
text_hash['1627207:28320'] = 'text'
text_hash
```