# Paper trail string to hash

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, hash, paper-trail-gem

Is it possible to convert a string to a hash so it can be iterated over like a hash?

```
"---
!ruby/hash:ActiveSupport::HashWithIndifferentAccess\ndescription:\n-
Original text blah blah.\n- New text blah blah.\nupdated_at:\n- 2014-05-12 09:18:21.000000000 Z\n-
2014-05-12 09:19:33.748593000 Z\n"
```

I'm using the `paper_trail` gem and trying to do diffing of non-adjacent versions. This prevents me from using the built-in `"changeset"` hash, which does what I want.

Using many regexes, I could deal with these strings, but I want to turn them into hashes where `"description"` would be taken as a key and the next two items would be `value.first` and `value.last`.

The string is called with `<%= version.object_changes %>`. How could I call that as a hash?

Comment: possible duplicate of [String to Hash convertion](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/10410470/string-to-hash-convertion)

Comment: How was this string was created?

Comment: It's created automatically by the paper_trail gem.

Comment: As for the possible duplicate, I can't make any sense of how to implement that answer for this problem.

Answer (score 11, accepted):

You should use [`version.changeset`](https://github.com/airblade/paper_trail#diffing-versions) to get a parsed hash of the objects changes.

If you really want to convert that string into the ruby object (`ActiveSupport::HashWithIndifferentAccess`), you can:

```
str = "--- !ruby/hash:ActiveSupport::HashWithIndifferentAccess\ndescription..."
YAML.load(str)
# => {"description"=>["Original text blah blah.", "New text blah blah."], "updated_at"=>[2014-05-12 09:18:21 UTC, 2014-05-12 09:19:33 UTC]}

# or
PaperTrail.serializer.load(str)
```

see [Papertrail::VersionConcern.changeset](https://github.com/airblade/paper_trail/blob/master/lib/paper_trail/version_concern.rb#L155)

Comment: I don't think I can use version.changeset. As I said above I'm looking at nonadjacent versions so I can't call changeset at all. I'm looking at all versions across all types for my site. That doesn't work with change set. Where would you put the code you've got there? In the model?

Comment: Heyyyy! "PaperTrail.serializer.load(str)" is a great way of doing it. That's using PaperTrail's method in a way they hadn't thought of right? Excellent. Great answer.