# Split a string in Ruby

Tags: ruby

I have a hash returned to me in ruby

```
test_string = "{cat=6,bear=2,mouse=1,tiger=4}"
```

I need to get a list of these items in this form ordered by the number.

```
animals = [cat, tiger, bear, mouse]
```

My thoughts were to_s this in ruby and split on the '=' character. Then try to order them and put in a new list. Is there an easy way to do this in ruby? Sample code would be greatly appreciated.

Comment: It's unclear what you're asking here.  Do you have the data in your first code block as a Hash object, or as a string representing a hash object?

Comment: a string representing a hash object.

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1667630/how-do-i-convert-a-string-object-into-a-hash-object  perhaps that will help especially the answer about splitting?

Comment: You don't need to `to_s` it, it's already a string.

Comment: He doesn't use the standard `Hash#to_s`representation though. No hashrockets.

Comment: That is the problem. I have only the '=' charter and it is sent to me from the client. I cant change it. I need to convert it to rockets

Comment: I don't understand the question. Do you want a string `{cat=6,bear=2,mouse=1,tiger=4}` to be converted into `[cat, tiger, bear, mouse]` or an hash?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
 a = test_string.split('{')[1].split('}').first.split(',')
 # => ["cat=6", "bear=2", "mouse=1", "tiger=4"]
 a.map{|s| s.split('=')}.sort_by{|p| p[1].to_i}.reverse.map(&:first)
 # => ["cat", "tiger", "bear", "mouse"]
```

Answer (score 7):

```
s = "{cat=6,bear=2,mouse=1,tiger=4}"

a = s.scan(/(\w+)=(\d+)/)
p a.sort_by { |x| x[1].to_i }.reverse.map(&:first)
```

Answer (score 1):

Not the most elegant way to do it, but it works:

`test_string.gsub(/[{}]/, "").split(",").map {|x| x.split("=")}.sort_by {|x| x[1].to_i}.reverse.map {|x| x[0].strip}`

Answer (score 1):

The below code should do it.
Explained the steps inline

```
test_string.gsub!(/{|}/, "") # Remove the curly braces
array = test_string.split(",") # Split on comma
array1= [] 
array.each {|word|
    array1<<word.split("=") # Create an array of arrays
}
h1 = Hash[*array1.flatten] # Convert Array into Hash
puts h1.keys.sort {|a, b| h1[b] <=> h1[a]} # Print keys of the hash based on sorted values
```

Answer (score 0):

```
test_string = "{cat=6,bear=2,mouse=1,tiger=4}"
Hash[*test_string.scan(/\w+/)].sort_by{|k,v| v.to_i }.map(&:first).reverse
#=> ["cat", "tiger", "bear", "mouse"]
```