# How to convert a find_by_sql hstore string to a hash in Ruby on Rails

Tags: ruby-on-rails, postgresql, ruby-on-rails-3.2, hstore

This seems ludicrously simple but I cannot figure out how to convert a hash-string to a hash.

When I do a Answer.find_by_sql I get a string like this

```
deepthought = "\"answertolife\"=>\"42\""
```

But I cannot figure out how to turn that into a hash.

I have tried:

```
pry(main)> Hash[deepthought]
ArgumentError: odd number of arguments for Hash
pry(main)> JSON.parse deepthought
JSON::ParserError: 757: unexpected token at '"answertolife"=>"42"'
pry(main)> deepthought.to_json
=> "\"\\\"answertolife\\\"=>\\\"42\\\"\""
```

I saw [How do I convert a String object into a Hash object?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1667630/how-do-i-convert-a-string-object-into-a-hash-object), but I still cannot figure it out.

Comment: And what does your `find_by_sql` look like?

Comment: This is inside a large SQL query. Simplified it would be something like `Answer.find_by_sql("SELECT answers.id AS aid, answers.deepthought AS deepthought FROM answers")`

Comment: I think you're stuck with unpleasant kludges unless you can upgrade to Rails4 which supports the hstore datatype natively. You could have a look at how Rails4 parses hstore inside the driver and mimic that.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Rails4 supports hstore out of the box so I'd probably handle the string casting the same way Rails4 does it. If you look inside the Rails4 PostgreSQL-specific casting code, you'll find [`string_to_hstore`](https://github.com/rails/rails/blob/v4.0.4/activerecord/lib/active_record/connection_adapters/postgresql/cast.rb#L48):

```
def string_to_hstore(string)
  if string.nil?
    nil
  elsif String === string
    Hash[string.scan(HstorePair).map { |k, v|
      v = v.upcase == 'NULL' ? nil : v.gsub(/\A"(.*)"\Z/m,'\1').gsub(/\\(.)/, '\1')
      k = k.gsub(/\A"(.*)"\Z/m,'\1').gsub(/\\(.)/, '\1')
      [k, v]
    }]
  else
    string
  end
end
```

and a little lower down in the same file, you'll find [`HstorePair`](https://github.com/rails/rails/blob/v4.0.4/activerecord/lib/active_record/connection_adapters/postgresql/cast.rb#L127):

```
HstorePair = begin
  quoted_string = /"[^"\\]*(?:\\.[^"\\]*)*"/
  unquoted_string = /(?:\\.|[^\s,])[^\s=,\\]*(?:\\.[^\s=,\\]*|=[^,>])*/
  /(#{quoted_string}|#{unquoted_string})\s*=>\s*(#{quoted_string}|#{unquoted_string})/
end
```

Stash that somewhere convenient (probably somewhere in `lib/`) and send your hstore strings through that `string_to_hstore` to unpack them into Hashes.

Comment: Thanks. That's much cleaner.

Answer (score 2):

Try this

```
eval("{ #{deepthought} }")
```

It wraps the deepthought string with curly brace  { }, and then use eval

Comment: Thanks. I read on the linked post that this has some severe security risks. I don't have control of the answers inserted here and it seems like a malicious user could insert ruby.

Answer (score 2):

A bit late but if you need to convert a multiple entries this works great.

```
def hstore_to_hash(hstore)
  values = {}
  hstore.gsub(/"/, '').split(",").each do |hstore_entry|
    each_element = hstore_entry.split("=>")
    values[each_element[0]] = each_element[1]
  end
  values
end
```

Answer (score 0):

This seems to work but feels dirty.

```
JSON.parse "{ #{deepthought} }".gsub('=>', ':')
```