# How to read and use a ruby json string

Tags: ruby, cloud-foundry

I am not an expert of Ruby and I try to use elements from a string that was part of a big JSON message. I never been able to use JSON.parse for whatever reason but was able to find a way to loop over the object. But at the end, I have this remaining string that I don't know how to get the value:

```
{:time=>"2014-09-11 10:59:27 +0000", :cpu=>0.02421584874444766, :mem=>192069632, :disk=>635125760}
```

This is attached to a variable called appUsage. If I try appUsage["cpu"] I obtained: cpu. I have tried couple looping suggestion from research on Internet but I just don't know enough Ruby - I guess - to know the right one that will works.

P.S.: For those who would like to know where this "string" is coming from, this is the result that coming from the app.stats from the library of CFoundry.

Comment: so you mean `appUsage = '{:time=>"2014-09-11 10:59:27 +0000", :cpu=>0.02421584874444766, :mem=>192069632, :disk=>635125760}'` it's a string you are getting?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

That's a ruby [Hash](http://ruby-doc.org/core-2.1.2/Hash.html) (not a String) containing what it seems like a Date, Float and Fixnum objects

You were close trying appUsage["cpu"] but the keys in your Hash are [symbols](http://www.ruby-doc.org/core-2.1.2/Symbol.html) rather than string, meaining its :cpu not "cpu" and yes ruby Hash treats each as a different key.

```
app_usage = {:time=>"2014-09-11 10:59:27 +0000", :cpu=>0.02421584874444766, :mem=>192069632, :disk=>635125760}

app_usage[:cpu]
# > 0.02421584874444766

app_usage[:disk]
# > 635125760
```

To convert your string to a hash to use it like written above use `eval()`.
In your case, if you have a string called `a` you can turn your string to hash by calling `eval(a)`, and then you can use your hash:

```
a = "{:cpu=>0.02421584874444766, :mem=>192069632, :disk=>635125760}"
app_usage = eval(a)
app_usage[:cpu] # => 0.02421584874444766
```

But as stated in [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1667630/how-do-i-convert-a-string-object-into-a-hash-object) answer:

> It has severe security implications. It executes whatever it is
>   passed, you must be 110% sure (as in, at least no user input anywhere
>   along the way) it would contain only properly formed hashes or
>   unexpected bugs/horrible creatures from outer space might start
>   popping up.

Comment: Thank you for your great explication. So you made me learn the "hash" aspect of Ruby! ;-)

Answer (score 0):

**What I got from you question:**

`'{:time=>"2014-09-11 10:59:27 +0000", :cpu=>0.02421584874444766, :mem=>192069632, :disk=>635125760}'` is a string.

That means:

```
appUsage = '{:time=>"2014-09-11 10:59:27 +0000", :cpu=>0.02421584874444766, :mem=>192069632, :disk=>635125760}'
```

So we have to convert this `String` object into `Hash` object.
And there is a dirty way to do this. :p

```
appUsage = eval '{:time=>"2014-09-11 10:59:27 +0000", :cpu=>0.02421584874444766, :mem=>192069632, :disk=>635125760}'
```

For more details check [this thread](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1667630/how-do-i-convert-a-string-object-into-a-hash-object) out.