# How to convert this 'hash-like' string to a key value pair

Tags: ruby

I'm using Ruby 2.2 and have a string that looks like this:

```
myvar = '{"myval1"=>"value1","mayval2"=>"value2"}'
```

How can I get this into a key-value pair and/or hash of some sort?  When I do `myvar['myval1']` I get back `'myval1'`, which isn't quite what I'm after.  The answer's probably staring right at me but nothing's worked so far.

Comment: I lost my close vote, but this is a duplicate. [How do I convert a String object into a Hash object?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1667630/how-do-i-convert-a-string-object-into-a-hash-object)

Comment: Where does that string come from? Is it possible to get the input in a different format?

Comment: @spickermann we're getting it back as part of an external api call, whose output we can't control.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can change that string to valid `JSON` easily and use `JSON.parse` then:

```
require 'JSON'
myvar = '{"myval1"=>"value1","mayval2"=>"value2"}'

hash = JSON.parse(myvar.gsub(/=>/, ': '))
#=> { "myval1"  => "value1", "mayval2" => "value2" }

hash['myval1']
#=> "value1"
```

Comment: you might want to read [my answer](http://stackoverflow.com/a/37009796/2423164), which expands on the subject. I hope you find it stimulating (or at least entertaining).

Answer (score 3):

As I've seen times and times again - simply mentioning `eval` makes people instantly upset, even if it was a proper use case (which this is not).

So I'm going to go with another hate magnet - parsing nested structures with regexes.

---

Iteration (1) - a naive approach:

```
JSON.parse(myvar.gsub(/=>/, ':'))
```

Problem - will mess up your data if the string key/values contain `=>`.

---

Iteration (2) - even number of `"`s remaining mean you are not inside a string:

```
JSON.parse(myvar.gsub(/=>(?=(?:[^"]*"){2}*[^"]*$)/, ':'))
```

Problem - there might be a `"` inside a string, that is escaped with a slash.

---

Iteration (3) - like iteration (2), but count only `"` that are preceded by unescaped slashes. An unescaped slash would be a sequence of odd number of slashes:

```
eq_gt_finder = /(?<non_quote>
                  (?:
                     [^"\\]|
                     \\{2}*\\.
                  )*
                ){0}
                =>(?=
                     (?:
                        \g<non_quote>
                        "
                        \g<non_quote>
                     ){2}*
                     $
                  )/x
JSON.parse(myvar.gsub(eq_gt_finder, ':'))
```

[See it in action](http://rubular.com/r/SgmUpFm20m)

---

**Q:** Are you an infallible divine creature that is absolutely certain this will work 100% of the time?

**A:** Nope.

**Q:** Isn't this slow and unreadable as shit?

[image: You're god damn right.]

**Q:** Ok?

**A:** Yep.