# How to turn into a hash what has been made into a string of a hash?

Tags: ruby, hash

I have this "hashed string" that I took from my Rails DB and I have to work with it as a hash. How do I make this

`str = "{ H: 50, Q: 25, D: 10, N: 5, P: 1 }"`

into this?

`str = { H: 50, Q: 25, D: 10, N: 5, P: 1 }`

Comment: Does this answer your question? [How do I convert a String object into a Hash object?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1667630/how-do-i-convert-a-string-object-into-a-hash-object)

Comment: Not really, Ken. I do not want to use JSON parse and eval in my environment to achieve my desired results. Unfortunately, none of those answers work. I've checked it before.

Comment: @VictorPark Are you stuck with this format, or can you switch to JSON?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```
str = "{ H: 50, Q: 25, D: 10, N: 5, P: 1 }"
```

```
str.gsub(/(\S+): +(\d+)/).with_object({}) { |_,h| h[$1.to_sym] = $2.to_i }
  #=> {:H=>50, :Q=>25, :D=>10, :N=>5, :P=>1}
```

This employs the form of [String#gsub](https://ruby-doc.org/core-2.7.0/Enumerator.html#method-i-with_object) that takes an argument and no block, returning an enumerator that can be chained to [Enumerator#with_object](https://ruby-doc.org/core-2.7.0/Enumerator.html#method-i-next). This form of `gsub` merely generates matches; it makes no substitutions.

One advantage of this construct is that it avoids the creation of temporary arrays.

The regular expression can be written in *free-spacing mode* to make it self-documenting.

```
/
(\S+)  # match 1+ characters other than whitespaces, save to capture group 1 
:[ ]+  # match ':' followed by 1+ spaces
(\d+)  # match 1+ digits, save to capture group 2
/x     # free-spacing regex definition mode
```

Comment: Thank you. This was, in my opinion, the best answer!

Answer (score 3):

### Scanning Strings for Key/Value Pairs

One approach that avoids running eval on potentially-tainted strings is to parse your string for keys and values using [String#scan](https://ruby-doc.org/core-2.7.1/String.html#method-i-scan), and then converting the resulting array into a hash using [Enumerable#each_slice](https://ruby-doc.org/core-2.7.1/Enumerable.html#method-i-each_slice) and [Array#to_h](https://ruby-doc.org/core-2.7.1/Array.html#method-i-to_h). If you like, you can also use [Hash#transform_keys](https://ruby-doc.org/core-2.7.1/Hash.html#method-i-transform_keys) to convert the resulting keys from strings to symbols with [String#to_sym](https://ruby-doc.org/core-2.7.1/String.html#method-i-to_sym), and [Hash#transform_values](https://ruby-doc.org/core-2.7.1/Hash.html#method-i-transform_values) to convert each value into an integer with [String#to_i](https://ruby-doc.org/core-2.7.1/String.html#method-i-to_i).

```
str = '{ H: 50, Q: 25, D: 10, N: 5, P: 1 }'
str.scan(/\p{Upper}(?=:)|\d+/).each_slice(2).to_h.
  transform_keys(&:to_sym).transform_values &:to_i
#=> {:H=>50, :Q=>25, :D=>10, :N=>5, :P=>1}
```

The regex used to scan for keys and values is tuned to your sample input, so it might need to be modified for other data. However, it certainly works for your posted example.

### Parsing as JSON

In comments, the OP stated that they didn't want to parse the string as JSON. As a general approach, it's conceptually simpler (and shorter) than the solution above, so I'll include it here for other visitors.

The main trick is that the OP's posted input won't parse as JSON unless you quote the keys. We can do that easily with the block form of [String#gsub](https://ruby-doc.org/core-2.7.1/String.html#method-i-gsub), and then parse the resulting valid JSON into a Ruby hash.

```
require 'json'

str = '{ H: 50, Q: 25, D: 10, N: 5, P: 1 }'
JSON.parse(str.gsub(/\p{Upper}(?=:)/) { %("#{$&}") }).transform_keys &:to_sym
#=> {:H=>50, :Q=>25, :D=>10, :N=>5, :P=>1}
```

Both approaches work equally well with the posted example. Parsing the data as JSON seems like it adds useful layers of input validation and programmer convenience, but individual use cases may certainly vary.

Answer (score 2):

Split the string on non-word characters into array. This splits on 1 or more characters that are not a letter, digit or underscore. Select from the array only words (this removes the first empty string). Slice the array into pairs of keys and values. Convert keys to symbols and values to integers. Convert the result into a hash. The whole sausage looks as follows:

```
str = '{ H: 50, Q: 25, D: 10, N: 5, P: 1 }'
a = str.split(/\W+/).grep(/\w+/).each_slice(2).map{ |k, v| [k.to_sym, v.to_i] }.to_h
puts a.inspect
# {:H=>50, :Q=>25, :D=>10, :N=>5, :P=>1}
```

Answer (score -1):

You can try it `eval(str)`

```
> str = "{ H: 50, Q: 25, D: 10, N: 5, P: 1 }"
> eval(str)
> => {:H=>50, :Q=>25, :D=>10, :N=>5, :P=>1}
```

Comment: `eval` is almost always the wrong tool since it is incredibly easy for it to lead a remote-code-execution vulnerability where an attacker can make your application execute any attacker-provided code. A restricted parser as proposed in the other answers is usually much safer.

Comment: I agree. Unfortunately eval is not a good tool to do that.