# How do I save cookie hash key values in seperate db fields rails 7?

Tags: ruby, ruby-on-rails-7

I'm using rails 7 and ruby 3.1.2.

My cookie I've created returns these keys and values:

```
>>  cookies[:utm_params]
=> "{:source=>\"facebook\", :medium=>\"facebook_feed\", :campaign=>\"123123123123\", :max_age=>2592000}"
```

And I've created these fields on my Subscription model:

```
#  utm_source             :string
#  utm_medium             :string
#  utm_campaign           :string
```

My Subscription.create code looks like this atm, but I can't figure out how to save them.

```
      @subscription = Subscription.create!({
        utm_source: cookies[:utm_params][:source],
        # utm_medium: cookies[:utm_params],
        # utm_campaign: cookies[:utm_params],
      })
```

EDIT: My own solution and refactor

```
application_controller.rb
UTM_COOKIE_NAME = "_ta_utm"

before_action :capture_utm_params

private

def capture_utm_params
  if(params.has_key?(:utm_medium))
    cookies[UTM_COOKIE_NAME] = { 
      expires: 30.days.from_now,
      value: {
        source: params[:utm_source],
        medium: params[:utm_medium],
        campaign: params[:utm_campaign]
      }.to_json
    }
  end
end

checkout_controller.rb
utm_tags = JSON.parse(cookies[UTM_COOKIE_NAME]) rescue nil
if utm_tags.present?
  source = utm_tags["source"]
  medium = utm_tags["medium"]
  campaign = utm_tags["campaign"]
end

@subscription = Subscription.create!({
  utm_source: source,
  utm_medium: medium,
  utm_campaign: campaign
})
```

Comment: The value in your cookie is a serialized Ruby hash which is not easily and safely parseable. Is it an option to serialize it in a different format?

Answer (score 0):

You need to convert that string in to hash. I tried to use `JSON.parse(string)` on your string but it is not parsable as json. So i found this [answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/25205872/5194116) for you to convert that string into hash so that you can save the data you want. Hope it helps.

you can use the code in the answer i linked like this:

```
utm_hash = JSON.parse(cookies[:utm_params].gsub(/:([a-zA-z]+)/,'"\\1"').gsub('=>', ': ')).symbolize_keys
```

Comment: if you mean `cookies[:utm_params].to_json` then it will not change anything. the way utm_params set in the cookie is not easily parsable. i recommend store the utm_params data as JSON parsable format so that you can easliy parse with `JSON.parse(cookies[:utm_params])` or you can use the above code for your current string.

Comment: I got it working, edited my original post above :)